# Android Client/Server socket confusion concept on moving forward

Tags: java, sockets, server

I'm trying to learn about client/server and sockets right now but I'm confused on the bigger scope of things. I followed a tutorial that has a client as an android app and the server is a java application. I run both of them on eclipse fine.

My question now is how do I make this global? So I'll take my server code written in java, export it to a text called server.java, and then upload it to my personal site? And then when I start my client android app, I'll make a call to say http://blah.com/server.java to start my server, right? Then my server will begin listening on that port and my client can connect to it?

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SimpleTextServer {

private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String message;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); // Server socket

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
    }

    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

    while (true) {
        try {

            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);

            //will later add an output stream to write back to android

            inputStreamReader.close();
            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: no, that file has to be running on the server that you upload it to. 
you just compile/export a jar, upload that to your server, and start it. then you tell android to talk to `blah.com:4444`

Comment: `I run both of them on eclipse fine.`. That is not even possible. With Eclipse you can produce apps for Android. But apps run on an emulator or on a real device. Your java server can run in your pc.

Comment: `I'll make a call to say http://blah.com/server.java to start my server`. No not http is it. You don't use the http protocol. In the Android code you just have to change the ip. That's all. Change it to your servers ip or host name. The java server should already be running on your internet server. Do you have a  hosting where you can run such servers?

Comment: On eclipse, I run the client as on the emulator and the server as a Java applet.

Comment: I "bought" a domain name and web hosting recently. Would that work? Or would I have to get something like a vps for me to upload my server code? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: why is bought in quotes? and no, you need a vps to run your java code.

Comment: You're not really buying the domain and web hosting... it's renting, isn't it? 

Would amazon's web service work? They have a free 12 month trial